# iphone sdk - expected identifier error

Tags: iphone, xcode, nsurl

i'm trying to load up a url with the value of the input field added to the end of the url and it errors with "expected identitifer" :(

```
[self fetchURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://localhost/test/script.php?name=%@&",[[urlField text]]]];
```

what have I done wrong?

Comment: edited as per below, now errors with: "A connection failure occured. The operation couldn't be completed. Connection refused."

Comment: If you're still struggling with this, you should post it as a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

You have missed the bracket

```
[self fetchURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://localhost/test/script.php?name=%@&",[[urlField text]]]]];
```

OR try instead

```
    NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://localhost/test/script.php?name=%@&",[urlField text]];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    [self fetchURL:url];
```